# About attributes, methods in JAVA

Tags: java, methods

I'm doing a program, and that program has student data.

In my `Student` class it has the following content:

```
public class Student{
    String capital;
    double note;
    int registration;
}
```

In my 'Info' class it has the following content:

```
public class Info{

    static string name;
    static String address;
    static int age;
```

And in my 'Main' class it has the following content:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        currentStudent Student = New Student ();

        current.Student.capital= "Peter";
        currentStudent.note = 8.0;
        currentStudent.registration= 876;


        Info f = new Info();

        Info.name= "Peter";
        Info.address= "Boulevard treet";
        Info.age= 43;

}
```

How do I change the 'capital' attribute of the 'Student' class so that this attribute is now of the 'Info' type. nd how do I assign this instance to a 'student'?

Comment: Why is all the data in your `Info` class static? Also, your `Student` class has no "owner" attribute, so if you want one, just make one and type it correctly. But read up on how to write classes, and how to write constructors that set instance values, because the idea of them is that you pass all values that you want your object instance to have as part of the constructor call. That's its job: to "construct" your instance. The kind of code that requires argument-less construction and then direct assignment as separate step are few and far between.

Comment: Your `Student` class does not have an `owner` field. Did you just want to add one of type `Info`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in java and I don't know many things. I also realized that I wrote some wrong information, I just corrected. So, basically I need to make the 'capital' attribute of the ' Student' class to be of the type 'Info'.

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language. If you define a class field as `String capital;` then capital can only be a String. So If your question is how you can assign an object of type `Info` to `String capital` the simple answer is: You can't. It's impossible

Comment: But the type in question is 'Info' and not 'String'. Maybe info.capital (?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SAMPLE of Info class

```
public class Info {
    String capital;
    String state;
}
```

Student class is

```
public class Student {
    Info addressInfo;
}
```

And another class to call student

```
public class School {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student();
        Info i = new Info();
        i.capital = "Chandigarh";
        i.state = "Haryana";
        s.addressInfo = i;
        System.out.println(s.addressInfo.state);
        System.out.println(s.addressInfo.capital);  
    }
}
```

I hope this answer meet your question